# Avro allow blank JSON/hash for nested attributes

Tags: schema, avro

Need to Create Avro schema for this ->

```
 {"city":"XXXXXX", "brand":"YYYY", "discount": {} }
 {"city":"XXXXXX", "brand":"YYYY", "discount": {"name": "Freedom", "value": 100} }
 {"city":"XXXXXX", "brand":"YYYY", "discount": {"name": "Festive Sale", "value": 100} }
```

I tried with the below shemas, which do not work:

```
    { "type":"record", "name":"simple_avro", 
      "fields":[ { "name":"city", "type":"string" }, 
                 { "name":"brand", "type":"string" }, 
                 { "name":"discount",
                   "type":{ "type":"record", "name":"discount", "default":"",  
                     "fields":[ { "name":"discount_name", "type":"string", "default":"null" }, 
                                { "name":"discount_value", "type":"float", "default":0 } 
                              ] }} 
               ] }
```

For discount field, I have tried default to as `"[]", "{}", ""`, but none of these work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think an empty `{}` object is allowed in any case, but if you want to allow no object at all, then it needs to be [a union type](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/spec.html#Unions), as designated by an array for the type, the the default value goes on the outer field rather than inside the record body

```
{ "name":"discount",
  "type" : [
    "null", 
    { "type":"record", "name":"discount", "fields": [...] } 
  ], 
  "default" : "null"
```

In general, I find that easier to express [in IDL format](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/idl.html#unions)

Then, a valid message could be `{"city":"XXXXXX", "brand":"YYYY"}`

Comment: its true that ```{}``` is not allowed.
Not exactly a solution, but one work-around that I implemented is that I used map instead of a record, which allowed ```{}```, but then I had to change the datatype of all the elements to string.